# fail2ban not starting jails

Tags: debian, iptables, fail2ban, jail

I'm going nuts on my live server where fail2ban is not starting jails anymore.

When i start fail2ban, everything looks fine:

```
fail2ban-client -x start:
2017-11-14 15:51:32,403 fail2ban.server : INFO   Starting Fail2ban v0.8.6
2017-11-14 15:51:32,403 fail2ban.server : INFO   Starting in daemon mode
```

When i look at the jail status:

```
fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      0
`- Jail list:
```

The few lines showing in the log /var/log/fail2ban.log are:

```
2017-11-14 15:51:32,443 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.6
2017-11-14 15:51:32,444 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh'
2017-11-14 15:51:32,445 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' uses Gamin
2017-11-14 15:51:33,661 fail2ban.comm   : WARNING Invalid command: ['add', 'ssh', 'auto']
```

This is a default config, reinstalled fail2ban after a purge.
Anyone knows where i should look?

Running on Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l

Comment: Try to launch fail2ban as a service with sudo. You might lack privileges.

Comment: I'd say "Invalid command" is a pretty good place to start looking.

Comment: And please show your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
In /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf i changed:

```
backend = auto
to
backend = polling
```

On auto it uses gamin and that does not work.